# What is wrong with this program? From Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    int i;
    printf("Celsius Fahr\n");
    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
        printf("%7d %4.2f\n", i, convert(i));
    return 0;
}
int convert(int a) {
    float b;
    b=(1.8*a)+32;
    return b;
}
```

It gives me as output all the Fahrenheit numbers as zero. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Turn your compiler’s warnings up if it’s not warning you about not providing a return type for `convert`

Comment: The function `convert` has no defined return value, and no protoype. Moreover `main()` is an antique from 20th C.

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean with defined return value? I returned "b". (I forgot to add the prototype sorry)

Comment: Please don't guess and present a moving target. Post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. The function should return `float`. Moreover, since this is 21st C, never use `float` when you can use `double`.

Comment: replace `int convert` with `float convert` and move it before `main`

Comment: @IlyaBursov I'm such an idiot, what a dumb mistake, thank you very much for noticing!

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Note: treat the closing brace '}' as a separate statement.  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change  `main()`  to `int main()`.
2. Change `int convert(int a)` to `float convert(int a)`.
3. Add a *function prototype* `float convert(int);` before `int main()`.
4. Use proper indentation.

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
float convert(int); // Funtion prototype
int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("Celsius Fahr\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf("%7d %4.2f\n", i, convert(i));
    return 0;
}
float convert(int a)
{
    float b;
    b = (1.8 * a) + 32;
    return b;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
Celsius Fahr
      0 32.00
      1 33.80
      2 35.60
      3 37.40
      4 39.20
      5 41.00
      6 42.80
      7 44.60
      8 46.40
      9 48.20
     10 50.00
     11 51.80
     12 53.60
     13 55.40
     14 57.20
     15 59.00
     16 60.80
     17 62.60
     18 64.40
     19 66.20
```